# LoadObjectV2 notsupportedexception

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-ce, .net-cf-3.5

I created an usercontrol with a property of type `SetOfImageFilenames`:

```
[Serializable]
public class SetOfImageFilenames
{

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private string image_filename;
    public string ImageFilename
    {
        get { return image_filename; }
        set { image_filename = value; }
    }

    private string image_disabled_filename;
    public string ImgageDisabledFilename
    {
        get { return image_disabled_filename; }
        set { image_disabled_filename = value; }
    }

    private string image_pressed_filename;
    public string ImagePressedFilename
    {
        get { return image_pressed_filename; }
        set { image_pressed_filename = value; }
    }

    public SetOfImageFilenames()
    {
        this.name = "";
        this.image_filename = "";
        this.image_disabled_filename = "";
        this.image_pressed_filename = "";
    }

    public SetOfImageFilenames(string image_filename, string 
    image_disabled_filename, string image_pressed_filename)
        : this()
    {
        this.image_filename = image_filename;
        this.image_disabled_filename = image_disabled_filename;
        this.image_pressed_filename = image_pressed_filename;
    }

    public SetOfImageFilenames(string image_filename, string 
    image_disabled_filename)
        : this(image_filename, image_disabled_filename, "")
    {
    }

    public SetOfImageFilenames(string image_filename)
        : this(image_filename, "", "")
    {
    }


}
```

When I add the control to the toolbox and put into the form off-line, all is right, but I have a runtime error:

> NotSupportedException on method ResourceReader.LoadObjectV2
>
> Details:
>
> FinalTestPrj.exe
>
> NotSupportedException
>
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[CwLib.Controls.SetOfImageFilenames, CwControlsLib, Version=1.0.6327.29280, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>
> at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& 
>       typeCode)\par
>
> at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObject(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& 
>       typeCode)\par
>
> at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean 
>       ignoreCase)\par
>
> at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo 
>       culture)\par
>
> at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name)\par
>
> at FinalTestPrj.Form1.InitializeComponent()\par
>
> at FinalTestPrj.Form1..ctor()\par
>
> at FinalTestPrj.Program.Main()\par

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you deployed on your device the System.dll for compact framework version 1 that does not contain the definition for `LoadObjectV2`.

**Check the version of the System.dll you are using in your project references: in case change it to 3.5**

Comment: the system.dll version is ok, is 3.5. The problem raises when when I run the application, there are problems with the generic collections (List<T>) when are properties of a Custom Control